# Blackscreen on android - Codenameone

Tags: java, android, codenameone

My application is working fine in the simulator but when i run the android build on my phone it just gives a black screen. (i've tried on multiple android versions)

No errors or nothing.
I'm a total beginner when it comes to android...

Comment: Is there any useful information in LogCat?

Comment: There will always be information related to Activity launch in logcat; additionally you can insert your own logging to indicate progress through the program's UI methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a temporary regression with Android 4.3, which is now being fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply everything works fine now!